# Reacting to headset play/pause, next, and previous buttons

Tags: windows-phone-8

When I have a bluetooth headset connected, and I'm in an app like the built-in video player or Nokia Mix Radio, the play/pause, next, and previous buttons works as expected. My app uses the MediaPlayer control from http://playerframework.codeplex.com/, and it doesn't react to those events automatically. Is there an API to hook up to those events? Couldn't find any docs about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think these apps uses background audio agents to work like that.